# Error in unit test case with MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I am using MockRestServiceServer for unit testing my rest end point. I have one unit test in working condition when I use

```
mockServer.expect(requestTo(containsString(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH))).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess(response, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

But same fails when I use

```
mockServer.expect(requestTo(containsString(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH))).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
        .andRespond(withBadRequest().body("test").contentType( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

Here is complete code

```
@Test
public void testPost() {
    ClientHttpRequestFactory originalRequestFactory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

    try {
        WebTarget target = getRootTarget("/test").path("");

        String payLoad = ReadFile("src/test/resources/SamplePayload.html");
        String response = ReadFile("src/test/resources/SampleResponse.txt");
        Assert.assertNotNull(payLoad);
        Assert.assertNotNull(response);



        final javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> entity = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(payLoad, "text/plain");

        mockServer.expect(requestTo(containsString(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH))).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))


            .andRespond(withSuccess(response, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

            final Response mockResponse = target.request().post(entity);
            mockServer.verify();
            Assert.assertNotNull("Response must not be null", mockResponse.getEntity());
            Assert.assertEquals("Response does not have expected response code", 200, mockResponse.getStatus());
        } finally {
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(originalRequestFactory);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostWithEmptyBody() {
        ClientHttpRequestFactory originalRequestFactory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
        try{
            WebTarget target = getRootTarget("/test").path("");
            String entityBody = new String();


            final javax.ws.rs.client.Entity<String> entity = javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(entityBody, "text/plain");

            mockServer.expect(requestTo(containsString(ROOT_RESOURCE_PATH))).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withBadRequest().body("test").contentType( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            final Response response = target.request().post(entity);

            mockServer.verify();

            Assert.assertNotNull("Response must not be null", response.getEntity());

            Assert.assertEquals("Response does not have expected response code", 400, response.getStatus());
        }finally {
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(originalRequestFactory);
        }


    }
```

target.request().post() is funciton which just calls

```
resttemplate.postForEntity
```

In second test case I am expecting a status code of 400 but instead I am getting 500 .Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your RestTemplate not contains right MessageConvertor for resolving

> `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`.